# How to identify relation between HID /dev/input/* files and real hardware?

Tags: input-devices, touchscreen, input, xinput

My friend had problems with touchscreen (they are gone after two reboots) after her sister used her laptop and when I tried to help I didn't find a way to identify `/dev/input/*` files. One way I've found was to grep in `$ dmesg` (`/var/log/kern.log`) but it doesn't work for me.

Does any standard method exist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use the tool `lsinput` that you can get installing the package `input-utils`.

```
sudo apt-get install input-utils
sudo lsinput
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert on this (just looked a bit when trying to detect if an external mouse is connected, which is quite a treat)... have you tried this?

```
grep "/dev/input/event" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

there is a lot of info there. And no, I do not think IDs corresponds, I have 11 /dev/input/event# and 13 ID in xinput...

Comment: Thanks, but Xorg log didn't show all of them.

Answer (score 1):

And if you don't have Internet connection:
`cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep "Name\|Handlers"`

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/565543